# How to change button color when clicked in kivy

Tags: python, button, colors, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to change the button color when pressed to green. But it is somehow not working? Could anybody help?

```
            Button:
               pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
               size_hint:1,1
               text: "20"
               size: 30,30
               on_release:
                  background_color:1, 0, 0, 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
               on_release:
                  self.background_color = 1, 0, 0, 0
```